# Matlab : How do I ensure that the covariance matrix is positive definite when using Kalman Filter

Tags: linear-algebra, covariance, svd, eigenvalue, kalman-filter

For complex valued data, I am finding it hard to ensure that the covariance matrix is positive definite. Taking an example,

```
P =

  10.0000 +10.0000i        0                  0          
        0            10.0000 +10.0000i        0          
        0                  0            10.0000 +10.0000i
```

I can check for positive definiteness of P using the cholesky or the eigenvalues explained below.

(A)

```
[R1,p1] = chol(P)

R1 =

     []


p1 =

     1
```

Since p1 > 0, A is not positive definite

(B) Using eigen values : if the eigenvalues are positive, then P should be positive definite.

```
[r p]=eig(P)

r =

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1


p =

  10.0000 +10.0000i        0                  0          
        0            10.0000 +10.0000i        0          
    0                  0            10.0000 +10.0000i
```

However, doing `svd(P)` gives all positive eigenalues !!
Where am I going wrong and what should I do to prevent the P matrix from becoming non positive definite. During run time and real world scenarios it is very hard to ensure the postive definiteness of P. Is there a hack or a way out? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Checking positive definiteness on complex matrices:

First of all, an answer to [this question at math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333727/how-to-determine-if-a-matrix-is-positive-negative-definite-having-complex-eigen) says that:

> A necessary and sufficient condition for a complex matrix A to be
>     positive definite is that the Hermitian part 
>    `A_H = 1/2·(A+A^H)` is positive definite, 
>     where `A^H` denotes the conjugate transpose.

#### Why P matrix becomes non-positive definite:

Then, on the question of why P loses its "positive-definiteness", the usual culprit is floating point representation/arithmetic.

Standard Kalman filter algorithm can show **numerical stability problems** in some sensitive operations as taking the inverse of matrix S when calculating Kalman gain, or when applying optimizations as using the simplified expresion for error covariance on the update step `P+ = (I - K·H)·P-`.

There are other sources of error, as a buggy implementation or using wrong data (e.g. defining process/measure covariance matrices that are not positive definite themselves).

#### How to avoid the problem:

I will focus in the first source of error: numerical stability.
There are a number of alternatives commonly used to make Kalman filters more stable and avoid the covariance matrix problem:

- Correct small errors in P on each iteration ([formally not correct](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/168898-how-to-make-covariance-matrix-positive-semi-definite-psd), but works nicely). I have successfully used the simplistic `P = 1/2 (P + P')` with real matrices in the past, but there are more ellaborate schemes.
- Use a [square-root Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Square_root_form), or any other formulation that improves stability. Since they keep and update a kind of square root of P, the assymetries are not a problem anymore. They also reduce the positive definite problem in general.
- Go to 64 bit FP arithmetic. Much more stable than using single precision.
- Improve numerical conditioning by scaling some variables. Large magnitude differences between numbers worsen the inaccuracies, so if P mixes in the diagonal values in the order of 10^+3 with other values in the order of 10^-6, then change the unit of the latter variable to micro-whatever to reduce the gap.

Using one or a combination of these factors could work. However, I have not worked with Kalman filters in the complex domain, so let me know how it works for your case.

Comment: It should be mentioned that one of the classical ways to keep the Kalman Filter numerically stable, is to use the Joseph Form. [1](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f6d1/d824dd527799d2514d69442c7886d77693f7.pdf) [2](https://wolfweb.unr.edu/~fadali/EE782/DiscreteKF.pdf) [Wikipedia: search 'joseph form'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there might be an oversight in claiming that "**A complex matrix (say M) is positive definite if its Hermitian part is positive definite**". For instance, consider the matrix M = {{20, 2i, 2i}, {2i, 16, 7i}, {2i, 7i, 8}}. Its eigenvalues are {19.3934 - 0.649106i, 12.6855 + 6.34564i, 11.9211 - 5.69654i} which are complex, contradicting the positive definiteness claim.

Although the Hermitian part of M is a diagonal matrix with positive entries, it does not guarantee positive definiteness for M.